# how can I insert a footnote with numbers instead of symbols?

Tags: symbols, numbering, footnotes

I do hope you are doing well and everything is all right.

I'm writing a paper for a journal, and it's nearly finished. unfortunately at the latest steps to finish it, I faced a problem which would be when I used

```
\footnote{text}
```

LaTeX itself used symbols instead of numbers. I think it's supposed numbers to be used genuinely. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to TeX.SX. It's really impossible to answer without seeing your preamble, could you provide an MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). What I can say is, ordinarily, LaTeX uses numbers, which means it's probably been set up to use symbols somewhere along the line. If you've loaded a standardised template or document class this was likely deliberate

Comment: Also, for future reference, while your question is very kindly and pleasantly posed, the Stackexchange network sees itself as a repository of information, provided by means of questions and answers. It doesn't see itself as a chatroom, forum, or bulletin board. For this reason, friendly hellos and thank yous (whilst nice) are usually seen as a distraction. The model of the site isn't me helping you personally with a problem you have, it's: here is a problem that one may encounter and here are its solutions. Then other people who have the same problem will be able to learn from one question

Comment: LaTeX per default already uses numbers instead of symbols– try `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\footnote{text}
\end{document}`. => we *need* to see a complete example in order to give a good answer instead of just guessing…

Comment: BTW: if you're writing an article for a journal and are using their template they probably *want* symbols instead of numbers and will undo any changes anyway…

Answer (score 3):

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

For more options, see: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes